# Remove stopwords from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
dataframe['Text'] = dataframe['Text'].apply(lambda x : ' '.join([item for item in string.split(x.lower()) if item not in stopwords]))
```

I am removing the stop words from the dataframe. Logic is working fine, but when there is some empty row comes it gives error.

I have used dropna() but it will drop the whole line instead there is data in other column.

How to add condition in above logic that column Text should not null

Comment: What do you mean by "empty row"? NaN, empty string?

And what is the expected output in this case?

Comment: Please provide an example other users can try out.

Comment: What are you going to do with that cleaned text afterwards? Maybe you should check CountVectorized / TfidfVectorizer methods - they can do that "on the fly"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use before your logic,

```
dataframe.dropna(subset=['Text'], how='all')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `NaN` to empty `list` what is not easy - use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) or [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) by `Series` created by empty `lists`:

```
pos_tweets = [('I love this car', 'positive'),
('This view is amazing', 'positive'),
('I feel great this morning', 'positive'),
('I am so excited about the concert', 'positive'),
(None, 'positive')] 

df = pd.DataFrame(pos_tweets, columns= ["Text","col2"])
print (df)
                                Text      col2
0                    I love this car  positive
1               This view is amazing  positive
2          I feel great this morning  positive
3  I am so excited about the concert  positive
4                               None  positive

stopwords =  ['love','car','amazing']
s = pd.Series([[]], index=df.index)
df["Text"] = df["Text"].str.lower().str.split().mask(df["Text"].isnull(), s)
print (df)
                                        Text      col2
0                       [i, love, this, car]  positive
1                  [this, view, is, amazing]  positive
2            [i, feel, great, this, morning]  positive
3  [i, am, so, excited, about, the, concert]  positive
4                                         []  positive

df['Text']=df['Text'].apply(lambda x:' '.join([item for item in x if item not in stopwords]))
print (df)
                                Text      col2
0                             i this  positive
1                       this view is  positive
2          i feel great this morning  positive
3  i am so excited about the concert  positive
4                                     positive
```

Another solution:

```
stopwords =  ['love','car','amazing']
df["Text"]=df["Text"].str.lower().str.split().combine_first(pd.Series([[]], index=df.index))
print (df)
                                        Text      col2
0                       [i, love, this, car]  positive
1                  [this, view, is, amazing]  positive
2            [i, feel, great, this, morning]  positive
3  [i, am, so, excited, about, the, concert]  positive
4                                         []  positive
```