# Getting this typeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, pandas

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

df=pd.read_csv('twitDB.csv',header=None, sep=',',error_bad_lines=False,encoding='utf-8')

hula=df[[0,1,2,3]]
hula=hula.fillna(0)
hula['tweet'] = hula[0].astype(str) +hula[1].astype(str)+hula[2].astype(str)+hula[3].astype(str) 
dhole=hula["tweet"]


dhole = re.sub('\s+', ' ',dhole )
```

Getting this:

> Error: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Please include _complete_ error message.

Comment: Dhole is just a parameter.

Comment: print(repr(dhole))
0       1495596971.6034188::#Automotive #Auto EBC Gree...
1       1495596972.330948::New free stock photo of cit...
2       1495596972.775966::eBay: 1974 Volkswagen Beetl...

Name: tweet, dtype: object

Comment: Please make edits to your question instead of putting code snippets and listing error messages in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) or [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), because works with `Series` (array) and `re.sub` works with scalar:

```
dhole = dhole.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)
#or
dhole = dhole.str.replace('\s+', ' ')
```

Sample:

```
>>> hula = pd.DataFrame({'tweet':['ss      ddd s   ss','d         d','f       t       y']})
>>> dhole=hula["tweet"]
>>> print (dhole)
0    ss      ddd s   ss
1           d         d
2     f       t       y
Name: tweet, dtype: object

>>> dhole = dhole.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True)
>>> print (dhole)
0    ss ddd s ss
1            d d
2          f t y
Name: tweet, dtype: object
```

---

```
>>> dhole = dhole.str.replace('\s+', ' ')
>>> print (dhole)
0    ss ddd s ss
1            d d
2          f t y
Name: tweet, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you. Small advice in future - [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). good luck!

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44157005/how-can-i-enlarge-the-below-output-in-python-because-want-to-use-it-as-an-input) Does anyone know the answer to this question?

Comment: I check it now. What is problem? Is necessary split all words and create list of words in each cel? Can you explain more?

Comment: Yes, I want to split all words.

Comment: So it seems instead `ho = ho.to_frame(name=None)
a=ho.to_string(buf=None, columns=None, col_space=None, header=True, 
index=True, na_rep='NaN', formatters=None, float_format=None, 
sparsify=False, index_names=True, justify=None, line_width=None, 
max_rows=None, max_cols=None, show_dimensions=False)` need `ho = ho.str.split()`

Comment: Mayb help [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43391877/2901002) solution/