# How can I enlarge the below output in python because want to use it as an input somewhere else?

Tags: python-3.x, api, twitter

This is the code that I am using:

```
ho = ho.replace('((www\.[\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','URL',regex=True)
ho =ho.replace(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', regex=True)
ho =ho.replace('\'"',regex=True)

lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
stem = PorterStemmer()
fg=stem.stem(a)

eng_stopwords = stopwords.words('english') 
ho = ho.to_frame(name=None)
a=ho.to_string(buf=None, columns=None, col_space=None, header=True, 
index=True, na_rep='NaN', formatters=None, float_format=None, 
sparsify=False, index_names=True, justify=None, line_width=None, 
max_rows=None, max_cols=None, show_dimensions=False)
wordList = word_tokenize(fg)                                     

wordList = [word for word in wordList if word not in eng_stopwords]   
print (wordList)
```

while printing (a) I am getting the below output. I am not able to perform word tokenize on it properly.

```
                     tweet
0     1495596971.6034188automotive auto ebc greenstu...
1     1495596972.330948new free stock photo of city ...
2     1495596972.775966ebay 1974 volkswagen beetle -...
3     1495596975.6460807cars fly off a hidden speed ...
4     1495596978.12868rt @jiikae guys i think mario ...
```

These are the first 5 lines of the csv file:-

```
"1495596971.6034188::automotive auto ebc greenstuff 6000 series supreme 
truck and suv brake pads dp61603 https:\/\/t.co\/jpylzjyd5o cars\u2026 
https:\/\/t.co\/gfsbz6pkj7""display_text_range:[0140]source:""\u003ca 
href=\""https:\/\/dlvrit.com\/\"" 
rel=\""nofollow\""\u003edlvr.it\u003c\/a\u003e"""
"1495596972.330948::new free stock photo of city cars road 
https:\/\/t.co\/qbkgvkfgpp""display_text_range:[0"
"1495596972.775966::ebay: 1974 volkswagen beetle - classic 1952 custom 
conversion extremely rare 1974 vw beetle\u2026\u2026 
https:\/\/t.co\/wdsnf2pmo7""display_text_range:[0140]source:""\u003ca 
href=\""https:\/\/dlvrit.com\/\"" 
rel=\""nofollow\""\u003edlvr.it\u003c\/a\u003e"""
"1495596975.6460807::cars fly off a hidden speed bump 
https:\/\/t.co\/fliiqwt1rk https:\/\/t.co\/klx7kfooro""display_text_range:
[056]source:""\u003ca href=\""https:\/\/dlvrit.com\/\"" 
rel=\""nofollow\""\u003edlvr.it\u003c\/a\u003e"""
1495596978.12868::rt @jiikae: guys i think mario is going through a mid-life 
crisis. buying expensive cars using guns hanging out with proport\u2026
```

Comment: Could you upload the `twitDB.csv` ? Or post the first 5 lines of the `twitDB.csv`?

Comment: Just uploaded the first 5 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for list of all words - it split by all whitespaces - also need `ho['tweet']` for select column `tweet`:

```
wordList = word_tokenize(fg) 
#output is string
ho1=ho['tweet'].str.split()
     .apply(lambda x:' '.join([word for word in wordList if word not in eng_stopwords]))
```

Or:

```
wordList = word_tokenize(fg) 
#output is list
ho1=ho['tweet'].str.split()
               .apply(lambda x:[word for word in wordList if word not in eng_stopwords])
```

instead:

```
ho = ho.to_frame(name=None)
a=ho.to_string(buf=None, columns=None, col_space=None, header=True, 
index=True, na_rep='NaN', formatters=None, float_format=None, 
sparsify=False, index_names=True, justify=None, line_width=None, 
max_rows=None, max_cols=None, show_dimensions=False)
wordList = word_tokenize(fg) 
wordList = [word for word in wordList if word not in eng_stopwords]   
print (wordList)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
I am getting this error.

Comment: Ok, maybe need `ho` change to `ho['tweet']` if need process `tweet` column of dataframe.

Comment: @jezrael, it'll be good to state that in your answer `ho` is a `pandas.Series` and if it's a `pandas.DataFrame`, then accessing the column of interest would be needed, e.g.  `ho['tweet']`